# Using "ref" in a v-form in a component being rendered multiple times with v-for

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

I´m trying to validate a v-form on a component that is used multiple times in it´s parent-component.

For some reason, the "ref" on the child-component does not seem to work on a <v-form>. It appearently works on the <v-window-item> though, (see console output below)

Let´s say i have this parent.vue

```html
<template>
  <v-card>
    <v-window v-model="currentStep" touchless>
      <child-component v-for="page in pages" ref="criteriaData" :key="page"/>
    </v-window>
    <v-btn @click="nextPage">NEXT</v-btn>
  </v-card>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Parent',
  components: { ChildComponent },
  data() {
    return {
      currentStep: 0,
      pages: [0, 1]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    nextPage() {
      if (this.$refs.criteriaData[this.currentStep].validateComponent()) {
        this.currentStep++
        // do something else
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

and this is the child component

```html
<template>
  <v-window-item ref="outerRef">
    <v-form ref="criteriaForm" v-model="valid">
        <v-text-field
            v-model="value"
            :rules="required"
        />
    </v-form>
  </v-window-item>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'childComponent',
  data() {
    return {
      required: [ v => !!v || 'Required!' ],
      valid: null,
      value: 0
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log('mounted')
    console.log(this.$refs)
  },
  methods: {
    validateComponent() {
      console.log('ValidateComponent gets properly called')
      return this.$refs.criteriaForm.validate()
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

What I expected:
When i press the button, it should validate the component and, if it validates, go to the next page.

What happens: I get an Error. It seems the "criteriaForm" does not get added to the $refs

Browser-Console:

```
mounted
Object{ outerRef: {...} }
ValidateComponent gets properly called
[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: can't access property "validate", 
this.$refs.criteriaForm is undefined"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this async await method:

```
async validateComponent() {
      const { valid } = await this.$refs.criteriaForm.validate()

      if (valid) {
        console.log('Form is valid')
      }
    },
```

And your nextPage function will throw an error too, update:

from

```
this.$refs.criteriaData[currentStep].validateComponent()
```

to

```
this.$refs.criteriaData[this.currentStep].validateComponent()
```

Comment: Changing the method to be async does not alter the outcome.

2nd: Thanks, i edited the question. When simplifying the problem the missing 'this' seems to have slipped my attention.